# get amazon S3 to send http request upon file upload

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I need my nodejs application to receive a http request with a file name, when a file is uploaded in my S3 bucket.

I would like  some recommendations on the most simple/straight forward way to achieve this.

So far I see 3 ways to do this, but I feel Im overthinking this, and there surely exist better options:

**1/** file uploaded on s3 -> S3 send a notification to SNS -> SNS sends a http request to my application

**2/** file uploaded on s3 -> lambda function is triggered and sends a http request to my application

**3/** make my application watch the bucket on regular basis and do something when a file is uploaded

thanks

ps. yes, Im really new to amazon services :)

Comment: Lambda Lambda !

Answer (score 1):

1. SNS: Will work OK, but you'll have to manage the SNS topic subscription. You also won't have any control over the HTTP post's format.
2. Lambda: This is what I would go with. It gives you the most control.
3. How would you efficiently check for new objects exactly? This isn't a good solution.

You could also have S3 post the new object events to SQS, and configure your application to poll the SQS queue instead of listening for an HTTP request.

Answer (score 0):

**SNS**- If you want to call multiple services on updating S3 then I would suggest SNS. You can create a topic for SNS and there can have multiple subscribers to that topic. Later if you want to add more HTTP then it would be as simple as subscribing the topic.

**Lambda** - If you need to sent notification to only one HTTP endpoint then I would strongly recommend this.

**SQS** - You don't need SQL in this scenario. SQS is mainly for decoupling components and would be the best fit for microservices but you can use with other messaging systems as well

You don't need to build something on your on to regularly monitor the bucket for changes as already services there like Lambda, SNS etc.